# Live site using old, cached version of CSS (style.css?v=2)

Tags: css, browser-cache

I recently pushed changes to two pages on a live site. One page received the CSS changes, while the other appears to be using an old version of the CSS file.

In the Sources tab of Chrome Dev tools, the page that is correct has my CSS files as `style.css` and `mobile.css`, and the page that is displaying with the old CSS has these as `style.css?v=2` and `mobile.css?v=2`.

No amount of Cmd + Shift + R or Empty Cache and Hard Reload seems to be fixing this. What can I do to push these changes?

Maybe if I manually set:

```
<link href="css/style.css?v=3" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/mobile.css?v=3" rel="stylesheet">
```

..would that do it? Or something else?

Is it possible that it will just take some time for the live server to reflect these changes?

Comment: What I find odd about this is that `style.css?v=2` is the OLD version of the CSS file and not the new one

Comment: whereas when it is displaying the css file as `style.css` in Chrome Dev Tools, that is the version

Comment: You can edit the question with your findings instead leaving them in comments, it might get lost

Comment: If you're using php, you can easily ensure your CSS files aren't cached by appending the current time to them e.g. `<link href="css/style.css?v=<?php echo time() ?>" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @Tim Probably off topic, but are you using that kind of trick on your websites yourself? If you don't want the stylesheet to be cached, ever, then it's more efficient to simply put the whole content in a `<style>` element on the page rather than load a separate file. Saves a request!